# Remainder when $27^{40}$ is divided by $12$

Tags: binomial-theorem

What is the remainder when ${27}^{40}$ is divided by $12$ ?

The answer is supposed by $9$ but i’m getting it’s as $3$ . Please correct me in my approach to the problem.

This is how I did it :-

${27}^{40} = {(3^3)}^{40} = {3}^{120}$

$\frac{{3}^{120}}{12} = \frac{3^{119}}{4}$

Thus 
$\frac{{3}^{119}}{4} = \frac{(3^{4})^{29}3^3}{4}$

We can now expand ${81}^{29}$ by binomial theorem

$27(\binom{29}{0}(80)^{29} + \binom{29}{1}(80)^{28} + \binom{29}{2}(80)^{27}......+\binom{29}{29}1)$

As all the numbers is the parentheses except $\binom{29}{29}$ are multiples of $4$ we can remove it out of the parentheses

Thus we will have ,

$27(4K) + 27$

$4m + 4(6) +3$

$4n +3$
Where $k,m,n$ will be multiple of $4$ this gives remainder as 3
Please help me find the flaw . Thank you

Comment: $27^{40}\equiv3^{40}\equiv 9^{20}\pmod{12}$. We find $9^2\equiv 9\pmod{12}$ so $9^{20}\equiv9\pmod{12}$.

Comment: @SharktheUnknown thank you but I wanted to know what mistake I had made . If you could tell that I’d be really grateful!

Comment: Since you have simplify it at the second line, you have to multiply it again by 3 giving the desired result, that is $3(4n + 3) = 12n + 9$.

Comment: @Azlif Sorry I didn’t get you. Could you please explain a little bit more clearly? Where am I missing out ?

Comment: here $$ \frac{3^{120}}{12} = \frac{3^{119}}{4}$$

Comment: @Azlif what do you mean by simplify ? I just wrote the same expression in another way

Comment: in your answer, $3$ is the remainder when $3^{119}$ divided by $4$, but what  you want is $3^{120}$ divided by $12$.

Comment: @Azlif No I divided $3^{120}$ by 3 first which gives me $3^{119}$ then I divided it by $4$ so I basically divided it by $12$ only because $(3)(4) = 12$

Comment: $4n + 3 = 3^{119}$ right? Hence $12n + 9$ is $3^{120}$ which mean the remainder when $3^{120}$  divided by $12$ is $9$.

Comment: @Azlif thanks for bearing with me ! I get it now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your flaw: You can't simplify a fraction when you're looking for a remainder. For instance, the remainder when $15$ is divided by $10$ is $5$, but when $3$ is divided by $2$ you get $1$. So don't do the transition from $\frac{3^{120}}{12}$ to $\frac{3^{119}}{4}$ unless you take some care to remember that you did it, and knowing how it affects the result.

One way to correct for it is, as others have pointed out, to convert from $\frac{}{4}$ to $\frac{}{12}$ after you're done taking away all the whole numbers that the division results in (in other words, once you've found that the fractional part of the division is $.75$).

Comment: Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 5):

Everything you did so far is right.

To finish off, you have

$$
\frac{3^{120}}{12} = \frac{3^{119}}{4} = \frac{4n+3}{4} = n + \frac{3}{4} $$
where $n$ is an integer. Now note that 
$$
n + \frac{3}{4} = n + \frac{9}{12}$$
and you see the remainder is $9$.

Comment: I’m sorry but what I didn’t understand is , that in the conversion of $\frac{3^{120}}{12}$ to $\frac{3^{119}}{4}$ I already divided the number by 3. Why do we need to divide it again by 3 in the final answer ? Why don’t we just divide it by 4 since we’ve already divided it by 3 ?

Comment: @Aditi I never divided it again by $3$. The definition of the remainder when $x$ is divided by $q$ is the integer $r$ (satisfying $0 \leq r < q$) such that $\frac{x}{q} = n + \frac{r}{q}$, where $n$ is an integer. So the remainder when $7$ is divided by $3$ is $1$ because $\frac{7}{3} = 2 + \frac{1}{3}$. Here I showed $\frac{3^{120}}{12} = n + \frac{9}{12}$.

Comment: Ohh okay thank you very much for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

$27(4K) + 27$ is the numerator in your fraction $\frac{(3^{4})^{29}3^3}{4}$. Did you forget about the $4$ in the denominator? Here is another approach to solve the problem. The remainder of 27 in dividing by $12$ is $3.$ Thus the remainder of $27^{40}$ is the same as the remainder of $3^{40}$ which is $3(27^{13}).$ Replacing 27 by its remainder 3 we get to $3(3^{13})$ which is $3^{14}= 9(27^4)$. Replacing 27 by 3 we get to $9(3^4)=3^6=27^2$ Replacing $27$ by $3$ and we get the correct answer which is 9.

Comment: Ohhh yes ! I did forget the 4 ! Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: Thanks. Your application of binomial theorem was very smart.